# GZipStream Unzip files to a separate directory

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Hi this code is working for me but it is unzipping the files into the same directory. I want to unzip the files to a new directory. See code below

```
public void Main()
{

    DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(m_ProjectPath+m_Tool);

    foreach (FileInfo fileToDecompress in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
    {
        Decompress(fileToDecompress);
    }
}

public void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
{
    using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
    {
        string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
        string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(
              currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);

        using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
        {
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = 
                new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you have problem with - please clarify (so far there is only request for a feature). You may want to look into `System.IO.Path` class as it likely contain solution for whatever you have problem implementing.

Answer (score 0):

You're copying the `decompressedFileStream` to `newFileName` which is:

```
string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(
          currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);
```

Look at `newFileName` in your debugger; it's just the original file name, in the original directory, with the filename extension removed. If you want to copy it to a different directory you have to specify the directory, not copy the one from `currentFileName`. You want to know how to specify a directory? That will depend if you have a command-line application, a WinForm, WPF, ASP.NET, or Windows Store app.